# How can I redirect module imports with modern Python?

Tags: python, python-importlib

I am maintaining a python package in which I did some restructuring. Now, I want to support clients who still do `from my_package.old_subpackage.foo import Foo` instead of the new `from my_package.new_subpackage.foo import Foo`, without explicitly reintroducing many files that do the forwarding.  (`old_subpackage` still exists, but no longer contains `foo.py`.)

I have learned that there are "loaders" and "finders", and my impression was that I should implement a *loader* for my purpose, but I only managed to implement a *finder* so far:

```py
RENAMED_PACKAGES = {
    'my_package.old_subpackage.foo': 'my_package.new_subpackage.foo',
}

# TODO: ideally, we would not just implement a "finder", but also a "loader"
# (using the importlib.util.module_for_loader decorator); this would enable us
# to get module contents that also pass identity checks
class RenamedFinder:

    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path, target=None):
        renamed = RENAMED_PACKAGES.get(fullname)
        if renamed is not None:
            sys.stderr.write(
                f'WARNING: {fullname} was renamed to {renamed}; please adapt import accordingly!\n')
            return importlib.util.find_spec(renamed)
        return None

sys.meta_path.append(RenamedFinder())
```

https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/importlib.html#importlib.util.module_for_loader and related functionality, however, seem to be deprecated.  I know it's not a very pythonic thing I am trying to achieve, but I would be glad to learn that it's achievable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

On import of your package's `__init__.py`, you can place whatever objects you want into `sys.modules`, the values you put in there will be returned by `import` statements:

```
from . import new_package
from .new_package import module1, module2
import sys

sys.modules["my_lib.old_package"] = new_package
sys.modules["my_lib.old_package.module1"] = module1
sys.modules["my_lib.old_package.module2"] = module2
```

If someone now uses `import my_lib.old_package` or `import my_lib.old_package.module1` they will obtain a reference to `my_lib.new_package.module1`. Since the import machinery already finds the keys in the `sys.modules` dictionary, it never even begins looking for the old files.

If you want to avoid importing all the submodules immediately, you can emulate a bit of lazy loading by placing a module with a `__getattr__` in `sys.modules`:

```
from types import ModuleType
import importlib
import sys

class LazyModule(ModuleType):
 def __init__(self, name, mod_name):
  super().__init__(name)
  self.__mod_name = name

 def __getattr__(self, attr):
  if "_lazy_module" not in self.__dict__:
    self._lazy_module = importlib.import(self.__mod_name, package="my_lib")
  return self._lazy_module.__getattr__(attr)

sys.modules["my_lib.old_package"] = LazyModule("my_lib.old_package", "my_lib.new_package")
```

Comment: This is one approach. But a couple of caveats. This forces the loading of this submodule, of course. Also, it may result in *two different instances of the same module* if user-code uses *both* types of imports. Which could matter.

Comment: With a little bit more flair one can place _lazy loading_ properties on an object, and put that object in `sys.modules` so that the import happens on attribute access.

Comment: Why would they get difference instances though? Both `import my_lib.new_package.module1` and `my_lib.old_package.module1` would refer to the same `module1` instance. Same for `old_package`, they'd both refer to the same `new_package` instance.

Comment: Ah your right, it should be fine because the new module path is already cached when it's imported!

Comment: Great, I like this answer as well, and it is more likely the one I would put into production, since it is more maintainable. I have not yet decided which answer to accept – yours, which is what I would recommend to the general audience (and should therefore probably be the accepted one), or radekholy24's, which more directly answers the question I formulated, and maybe better addressed my curiosity about importlib.

Comment: I also found `importlib.util.LazyLoader` while poking around in the implementation. And I wondered if there should be a general-purpose python package for such legacy redirections.

Comment: There's an example how to use that lazy loader: https://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib.html#implementing-lazy-imports. You can surely make a little package out of it

Answer (score 3):

In the init file of the old module, have it import from the newer modules
Old (package.oldpkg):

```
foo = __import__("Path to new module")
```

New (package.newpkg):

```
class foo:
  bar = "thing"
```

so
package.oldpkg.foo.bar is the same as package.newpkg.foo.bar

Hope this helps!

Comment: Yes, this is something I considered as well, but my original point was to clean up the old package, removing lots of files that should never have been there. (Consider oldpackage being "image_processing" and moved submodules being "text_tokenizer.py" or so.)  Since there is a fair amount of small files I moved, I found it preferable to have a central place that does the redirection, without having to reintroduce such forwarding modules.

Comment: Also, note that in my example, `foo` was a module, not a class.  If there was a way to just modify one `__init__.py` and forward many contained modules, that would be ok as well, *but* I also did not want to trigger many unused imports just to make the modules visible for legacy clients.  I am looking for a way to intercept the imports that would otherwise fail.

Comment: I hope the new example works. I use yoru variables names word for word but hopefully you get the gist of it.

Answer (score 2):

I think that this is what you are looking for:

```py
RENAMED_PACKAGES = {
    'my_package.old_subpackage.foo': 'my_package.new_subpackage.foo',
}

class RenamedFinder:

    @classmethod
    def find_spec(cls, fullname, path, target=None):
        renamed = RENAMED_PACKAGES.get(fullname)
        if renamed is not None:
            sys.stderr.write(
                f'WARNING: {fullname} was renamed to {renamed}; please adapt import accordingly!\n')
            spec = importlib.util.find_spec(renamed)
            spec.loader = cls
            return spec
        return None

    @staticmethod
    def create_module(spec):
        return importlib.import_module(spec.name)

    @staticmethod
    def exec_module(module):
        pass

sys.meta_path.append(RenamedFinder())
```

Still, IMO [the approach that manipulates `sys.modules`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72244240/542196) is preferable as it is more readable, more explicit, and provides you much more control. It might become useful especially in further versions of your package when `my_package.new_subpackage.foo` starts to diverge from `my_package.old_subpackage.foo` while you would still need to provide the old one for backward compatibility. For that reason, you would maybe need to preserve the code of both anyway.

Comment: Awesome, this is indeed what I was looking for.  But I also agree that it is kind of "magic", and the reason I had to post this question in the first place is also an indicator that the documentation is hard to understand, and that I should reconsider whether I want to put this hard to maintain code into production.  It still satisfies me to see this work! :-)

Comment: BTW: Playing with your code, I found it helpful to split off the two new methods into a RenamedLoader class, so that finder and loader are not identical.  It might be common to have both in one class (IIRC I read something like that in the docs in the past), but that way the responsibilities are separated and interface pieces are grouped and properly named.

Answer (score 0):

Consolidate all the old package names into `my_package`.
Old packages (old_package):

- image_processing (class) Will be deleted and replaced by better_image_processing
- text_recognition (class) Will be deleted and replaced by better_text_recognition
- foo (variable) Will be moved to better_text_recognition
- still_there (class) Will not move

New packages:

- super_image_processing
- better_text_recognition

Redirector (class of my_package):

```py
class old_package:
   image_processing = super_image_processing # Will be replaced
   text_recognition = better_text_recognition # Will be replaced
```

Your main new module (my_package):

```py
#imports here
class super_image_processing:
  def its(gets,even,better):
    pass
class better_text_recognition:
  def now(better,than,ever):
    pass
class old_package:
   #Links
   image_processing = super_image_processing
   text_recognition = better_text_recognition
   still_there = __import__("path to unchanged module")
```

This allows you to delete some **files** and keep the rest. If you want to redirect variables you would do:

```py
class super_image_processing:
  def its(gets,even,better):
    pass
class better_text_recognition:
  def now(better,than,ever):
    pass
class old_package:
   #Links
   image_processing = super_image_processing
   text_recognition = better_text_recognition
   foo = text_recognition.foo
   still_there = __import__("path to unchanged module")
```

Would this work?

Comment: Thanks! I'll have to study this; it is not obvious to me whether/how this works. I was not aware at all that one could do `import my_package.old_package.foo` without an actual `old_package` *directory* containing a `foo.py` (but using `class` instead). If that is really the case, I can see how that would address my needs.

Comment: Hmm, I cannot get this to work. I know that a class also gets me a namespace, but it does not seem to be importable.  I can do `import my_package; print( my_package.old_package.Foo())`, but not `import  my_package.old_package`.

Comment: Actually add `def __init__(); pass` to my_package.old_package. ";"= Newline.

Comment: Yes, that would work, but I need to support `from my_package.image_processing.text_tokenizer import TextTokenizer`, and want to do that without actually introducing `my_package/image_processing/text_tokenizer.py`. (I even managed to do so, I am just not happy with my solution yet, because it does the actual import / compilation twice, but I would now also like to get *identical* results with the old and new imports.)

Comment: Make TextTokenizer a class, take the code that would be used in the TextTokenizer Function and put it in TextTokenizer.__init__ after this line `text_tokenizer = __import__("my_package/image_processing/text_tokenizer.py")`. Use that line specifically so the instance for text_tokenizer stays in the TextTokenizer class.

Comment: I'm not sure how this is supposed to work. For starters, it should break imports of the form `from library.some_package import some_name` since now `some_package` is a name in the module